# auto keyword in c++4.3.2

Tags: c++, auto

My doubt is that does "auto" keyword works in **C++4.3.2**? I was writing a program to check the presence of a prefix in a word, I wrote something like this --

```
auto res = mismatch(prefix,word);
```

And when I compiled it gave the error--

```
res was not declared in scope
```

What should I use in place of "auto" in case if "auto" is not available in c++4.3.2.

Here u can see my full code--  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9351873/

Comment: If only there were some sort of [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) that had a list of features and when they were addded...

Comment: For a given definition of "works", it works. See what version of the C++ standard (and features like "auto") is supported by your compiler version (assuming gnu c++) here:  https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: `4.3.2` appears to be a version of `g++`, a particular C++ compiler. There is no version `4.3.2` of the C++ *language*.

Answer (score 0):

@Surayans Tiwari

Return type of mismatch() is std::pair. Please refer following page and correct your usage.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I have the same opinion with @KeithThompson that you are talking about using GCC 4.3.2 instead of using C++ 4.3.2.

Assume that I perceive correctly, the compilation error that you got is due to the `auto` type is not supported in GCC 4.3.2 yet.

According to the C++11 support in GCC reference,
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
the `auto`-typed variables is supported since GCC 4.4.

If you wish to try the feature of `auto` type, you should use a newer GCC compiler.